# Dimension of pre-image of variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

My question is related to Andreas Gathmann's Algebraic Geometry notes (see [https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002-c4.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002-c4.pdf)). There is a step in the proof of Corollary 4.2.7 I cannot understand. He starts with a morphism of varieties $f:X\to Y$, and, after remarking that WLOG we can assume $Y\subset\mathbb{A}^m$ is affine, he takes a polynomial $f$ that vanishes somewhere on $Y$ but not everywhere, and takes $X'$ to be the pre-image under $f$ of some irreducible component of $Y\cap Z(f)$.

On page 57, he claims that $\mathrm{dim}(X')=\mathrm{dim}(X)-1$. Of course this is intuitively true, but can someone explain how this can be seen using the previous discussion on Dimension in the notes?

Comment: Perhaps his notation could be improved, given that there are two different maps $f$, and I think the explanation requires considering the polynomial, uh, $f \circ f$.